# How can I convert a string property to a custom type within a TypeScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, mongodb, interface

I have an interface that is extending a MongoDB document, and some sample data that is extending that interface.
The interface is like this:

```
export default interface IModel extends Document {
_id: ObjectId;
name: string;
data:string;

}
```

The sample data matches this interface. The object ID type looks like a string of numbers and letter. However, when I define a value for the sample data in the _id fields, it throws an error because TypeScript types it as a string and the type should be ObjectId. So how can I cast the value of the id to be of type ObjectId?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
export const ModelSampleData: IModel = {
"_id": toObjectId(240nfkfn38943),
"name": "model",
"data": "modelstuffetc"

}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What does `ObjectId` look like? In general to ignore any typechecking you can use `"mystring" as any as ObjectId`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

according to this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#generate-a-new-objectid), you can cast your string type to `objectId` like so:

```js
export const ModelSampleData: IModel = {
  "_id": ObjectId("240nfkfn38943"),
  "name": "model",
  "data": "modelstuffetc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove "", you tried to copy response and assign it to ModelSampleData which is json object, not javascript object, if you want to use then use JSON.parse
below both samples should work

```
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';

export default interface IModel extends Document{
    _id: ObjectId ;
    name: string;
    data:string;
}

export const ModelSampleData1: IModel = JSON.parse(`{
    "_id": ObjectId(240nfkfn38943),
    "name": "model",
    "data": "modelstuffetc"
}`);
```

or

```
export const ModelSampleData: IModel = <IModel> {
    _id:  new ObjectId("240nfkfn38943"),
    name: "model",
    data: "modelstuffetc"
}
```